# Comparing a particular key in 2 array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way with lodash, where in result I do not have an object that satisfies a particular condition. For example,

```
o1 = [
  {name: "a", id: 2, key: 33},
  ..,
]

o2 = [
 {name: "ab", id: 2, key: 133}
]
```

Is there a way with lodash where the resultant array only includes the object that does not have the ids already present in `o2`. For example, resultant object after comparing `o1` and `o2` must not have  the object from o2 because `id=2` already exists in `o1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `_.differenceBy()` and use the `id` of the point of reference:

```js
const o1 = [{id: 1, name: 'a'},{id: 2, name: 'b'},{id: 3, name: 'c'}]
const o2 = [{id: 1, name: 'b'}]

const result = _.differenceBy(o1, o2, 'id')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without lodash by using `.filter()` and creating a `Set`. Firstly, you can create a set of all the ids in `o2`. Then, you can filter out any objects from `o1` which have an id within the set. By using a set with `.has()` we are able to make our algorithm more efficient (than say using `.includes()` on an array).

See example below:

```js
const o1 = [
  {name: "a", id: 2, key: 33},
  {name: "b", id: 3, key: 34},
  {name: "c", id: 4, key: 34}
]

const o2 = [
  {name: "d", id: 2, key: 134}
]

const o2_ids = new Set(o2.map(({id}) => id));
const result = o1.filter(({id}) => !o2_ids.has(id));
console.log(result); // includes objects with id's that appear in o1 but not in o2
```

Comment: I will use your solution but accept the answer given by @OriDrori , since it gives a way with `_` :)

Comment: @Amanda no worries, Ori's was more focused on the question so all good :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`_.differenceWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#differenceWith)?

```js
const o1 = [
  {id: 1, name: "a"},
  {id: 2, name: "b"},
  {id: 3, name: "c"},
]

const o2 = [
  {id: 1, name: "b"},
]

const diffed = _.differenceWith(o1, o2, (o1, o2) => o1.id === o2.id)

console.log(diffed)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>


<script>
var o1 = [
  {name: "a", id: 77, key: 55},
  {name: "a", id: 2, key: 33},
  {name: "a", id: 1, key: 55}
]

var o2 = [
 {name: "ab", id: 88, key: 133},
 {name: "ab", id: 2, key: 133},
 {name: "ab", id: 99, key: 133}
]
//sort first

o1.sort((a, b) => {
 return a.id-b.id;//sort by id
});

o2.sort((a, b) => {
 return a.id-b.id;//sort by id
});


//then compare one by one
function SearchX(OO1,OO2){
 var o1_compare_place=0;
 var o2_compare_place=0;


 while(OO2.length>o2_compare_place && OO1.length>o1_compare_place ){
  if(OO2[o2_compare_place].id<OO1[o1_compare_place].id){
   o2_compare_place+=1;
  }else if(OO2[o2_compare_place].id>OO1[o1_compare_place].id){
   o1_compare_place+=1;
  }else{
   return "Exist Same!";
  }
 }
 return "Different!";

}

document.body.innerHTML = SearchX(o1,o2)







</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here you are